# After trigger to update several row in same table

Tags: mysql, triggers

Currently I'm trying to create a trigger that when the trigger fired it will update several record in same table.

```
After Insert TA
begin
    update TA
    set K = "W"
    where Z = NEW.Z;
end;
```

But the trigger will always stop the insertion, then I found some posts and they say it is because of table being locked. When I try to unlock the table but this cannot be done in the trigger.

currently I just split the table to 1:1 relation for this problem,  are there any others way you can do this?

Comment: Wouldn't this cause a cascading of triggers because you are updating more records in the table causing more triggers to fire?

Comment: this is insert event, wont fire when update